# Java Twitter4J not showing source label under tweets

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I've got Twitter4J implemented and sending tweets, however under the tweet there is no source label.

I'd like to show "sent from app name" or something along those lines.

Is this a setting within the Twitter account itself or something I need to do in Twitte4J?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The source label is determined by the configuration of the app in the Twitter Developer Portal. If your app is called “MyJavaApp” in the portal, that’s what it will show up as in the source label in Twitter itself and in the API responses.

The source label shows in the individual Tweet detail view, but not in the timeline view.